# how to pass parameter @Payload

Tags: spring-integration

i have code

```html
<int:channel id="partnerConfigChannel" />
<int:gateway id="partnerService" service-interface="org.service.PartnerService"
  default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000">
  <int:method name="findConfig" request-channel="partnerConfigChannel" />
</int:gateway>

<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway entity-manager="entityManager"
   request-channel="partnerConfigChannel"
  jpa-query="select q from QueueConfiguration q where q.partnerId = :partnerId">
  <int-jpa:parameter name="partnerId" expression="payload['partnerId']" />
</int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>
```

and java interface

```
public interface PartnerService {

    @Payload("partnerId")
    List<QueueConfiguration> findConfig();
}
```

i am calling it

```
List<QueueConfiguration> qc= partnerService.findConfig();
```

but i am getting exception 
**EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'partnerId' cannot be found on null**

please tell me how can i pass payload . i tried by passing Message object with a map , string but same error .
please tell me how can i pass payload in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Payload("partnerId")

At this point, there is no object for the SpEL expression to be evaluated against.

It either needs to be a literal

```
@Payload("'partnerId'")
```

Or refer to some other bean.

Further, on your adapter, you are expecting the payload to be a map with key `partnerId`.

```
expression="payload['partnerId']"
```

So this won't work.

If you want to pass a variable, you should do something like this...

public interface PartnerService {

```
List<QueueConfiguration> findConfig(MyClass param);
```

Where MyClass has some property 'partnerId'.

or

```
List<QueueConfiguration> findConfig(String partnerId);
```

and

```
expression="payload"
```

I suggest you do some more [reading](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

Answer (score 0):

i modified my code

```
public interface PartnerService {
List<QueueConfiguration> findConfig(@Payload Message msg);
```

}

and the call it like

```
Map msgMap=new HashMap();
msgMap.put("partnerId", partnerId);
Message msg=MessageBuilder.withPayload(msgMap).build();
List<QueueConfiguration> qc= partnerService.findConfig(msg);
```

and it is working fine.